# Why do we say "je vous demande" rather than "je vous demandez"?

Tags: grammaire, pronoms, conjugaison

I came across the sentence "Je vous demande pardon ?" in Lingvist and am wondering why "demander" is not being conjugated in the "vous" form, which would make it "demandez". Any insight would be appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*Je vous demande* means “I ask you.” Here, *vous* is an object of *demander*, not the subject, which is instead *je*. Hence, *demander* must be conjugated in accordance with *je*, not *vous*.

Because *vous* is an object pronoun, it is placed between the subject and verb; this may have caused confusion if you are very new to French. However, consider also that one says *s’il vous plaît* and *s’il te plaît* and not *s’il vous plaisez* or *s’il te plais*. In this common phrasebook expression, *il* is the subject, and that is the basis for conjugating *plaire*.